# queryTxt ETIMEOUT merncluster-0jdze.mongodb.net

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, cluster-computing

I'm using nodejs with MongoDB server using mongoose, whenever I try to run my server, it won't connect to my database. After sometime above log is seen on CMD. My cluster name is merncluster here!!

Is there any solution to this, I've searched a lot, still can't find proper solution to this, this keeps happening all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to [whitelist](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#connecting-ip-address-not-whitelisted) your IP address in MongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 8.8.8.8 to my connection to the internet works for me.

[image]